# What is the standard way to secure flex duct in an attic?

Tags: insulation, attic, ducts

I was in a house and noticed that flex duct (or what I think is flex duct) is being secured via a strap that's looped around the duct and then nailed to an attic truss (see picture below). Is this the proper way to secure flex duct?

[image: Flex Duct]

Comment: If that its a type of slip knot around the duct, that is not proper.  Otherwise, yes, they are just hung with webbing.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - What do you mean by webbing?

Comment: "Webbing" is a more technical term for that type of wide strap.  Seatbelt material is also called webbing - technical but also pretty generic word.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - If a slipknot is not used, does the webbing just go underneath the flex duct and get nailed to the truss?

Comment: The idea is to cradle the duct and try not to compress it as Ed has described below.  The installs I have seen don’t do the great job he describes, but they try to not crush the duct.  The duct in your picture has only had the insulation compressed, but over time more damage can happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That duct is not done properly notice how the duct is collapsed. Webbing can be used I have used plumbers tape (a metal strip with holes) at the first support after a rise I will screw a saddle of scrap ductwork to keep the duct from collapsing. I have used webbing but always think it will separate over time I usually melt the holes to reduce the chance of this but still make a saddle on the rise to spread the force out then support it regularly so it won’t collapse but nylon strapping is ok. I would want to fix that collapsed section a section of single wall duct like dryer duct opened up could make several sections of saddles.

Comment: I agree. The plumber's tape and scrap ductwork  works great.